# Creating an ERC20 faucet

Tags: solidity

I am trying to use this

https://github.com/marvinkruse/simple-faucet

what line number do I put in the address of my ERC20 token?

Is it line 16? and is it "address"  or "_tokenInstance"

Answer (score 0):

> what line number do I put in the address of my ERC20 token?

For the contract you've pointed to, you don't explicitly add the token address to the faucet contract code. (You *could* but you'd have to change the contract code slightly<sup>1</sup>.)

When a contract is deployed, a special function called the `constructor()` is called. This is the only time the constructor is ever called. When you deploy the contract, you pass certain variables that will be used by the constructor. In this case the constructor takes only one parameter: an address.

This address is the address of your ERC20 token, which must have already been deployed separately.

> Is it line 16? and is it "address" or "_tokenInstance"

In line 16, `address` is the type and `_tokenInstance` is the variable name. Together they constitute the definition of the parameter taken by the constructor. This *defines* the type of variable that must be passed to the constructor when it is invoked during contract deployment.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you want to do it the hard-coded way, replace `<add_token_address_here>` with the token address:

```
contract Faucet {
    uint256 constant public tokenAmount = 100000000000000000000;
    uint256 constant public waitTime = 30 minutes;

    ERC20 public tokenInstance = ERC20(<add_token_address_here>);
    
    mapping(address => uint256) lastAccessTime;

    constructor() public {
      // No longer require a constructor.
    }
    ....
```